# One website, two diffrent domains with one subfolder, possible?

Tags: iis, subdomain, subdirectory

I would like to put a website on two domains like the following:
www.abc.com/xyz
and
www.xyz.com

I don't want to do redirect. Is this possible? I am using IIS.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

yes, possible... you need 2 separate websites and you need to setup a virtual folder on the first one (abv.com/xyz) pointing to the folder of xyz.com

Comment: Thanks, sorry, I forgot to add that www.abc.com and www.xyz.com are two different machines. (We want to put the web application on a new machine but also want to use the subfolder)

Comment: So this is still an open question for me!